# Get the SUM of Items from Media library in all site collections in SP2010 using JavaScript

Tags: site-collection, sharepoint-server, client-object-model

How to get the SUM of Item Count from "Media" library in all site collections(more than 100) in SP2010 using JavaScript(or any other way).

I've more than 100 site collections and each site collection has Media library, each Media library has 'n' number of items.

Here I want to get the count for all Media files in all site collection in a web application.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible through the [jsom](/questions/tagged/jsom) as that only operates on the site collection it gets executed from.

You can achieve what you want using C#/VB or powershell.